# Is there a way to copy files one by one after doing a specific action on these?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code. Not being able to copy file one by one using the FSO function. I tried using f(for file) so it represents each file one by one but i don't think i am doing it right. Any way of doing this without the dir function?

```
 Dim myFSO As FileSystemObject
 Dim xFolder As Scripting.Folder
 Dim FSO As Object
 Dim f As File
 Dim sDFolder As String

sDFolder = "W:\Destination\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set myFSO = New FileSystemObject

Set xFolder = myFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\amzubaid\Desktop\ISIN- 
Compiler Temp")

For i = 1 To xFolder.Files.Count

FSO.CopyFile ("C:\Users\Tom\TestFolder\" & 
f), sDFolder, True

MsgBox "Specified File Copied Successfully", vbInformation, 
"Done!"

DostuffHere on each file one by one before deleting

On Error Resume Next

Kill "W:\Destination\*.*"

On Error GoTo 0

 Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure I understand why you're using 2 FileSystemObjects, but you can loop through the `.Files` collection with a `For Each` loop. Without seeing what you're doing with the copies, the `Kill` statement may belong outside the loop.

Comment: Noted. There're 2 filesystem objects because i looked at 2 different codes on internet to help me. THought it wouldn't make a different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Dim f
'...
'...
For Each f in xFolder.Files

    f.Copy sDFolder & f.Name

    MsgBox "File '" & f.Name & "' Copied Successfully", _
            vbInformation, "Done!"

    'DostuffHere on each file one by one before deleting

     On Error Resume Next
     Kill sDFolder & "*.*"
     On Error GoTo 0

Next f
```